# $X$ with a line(intersecting on one point) may not be homotopic equivalent to $X$?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

I felt weird when I tried to prove the statement of title.

> $X$ with a line(intersecting on one point) may be homotopic equivalent to $X$

If $X$ is Hausdorff, it's possible to prove. I have a positive result of this.

However, for arbitrary topological space, how to prove it? Is there any counterexample of the statement?

Comment: I do some mistakes in my approach.. I find a way, now

Comment: For the statement it's enough to find a Hausdorff counterexample.

Comment: I mean, I prove that the space is homotopic equivalent to $X$ when $X$ is hausdorff.. or is this also false..? (Now I see it is wrong-written. I editted the post. (may not $\to$ may)

Comment: I see now. Edit it back, that was better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line with two origins does not deformation retract on two origins. Now take $X=\{a,b\}$ with indiscrete topology and add it a line. Then it is isomorphic to the line with two origins where two origins are $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Oh. this is what I thought. I wasn't sure about it. Thanks.